# Silent Sms detection android

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to detect a silent sms through the android api. Also just for kicks, can you send one from a device?

Comment: Do you have any progress in your research so far?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "silent sms". Do you mean that when the SMS is sent or received, the user is not notified and never sees the message?

Comment: I have spent about a half hour on it, and have found one place that says its possible, but i havent found anywhere that confirms. not much else useful info, mostly just theory. Silent in this sense: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service#Silent_SMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright i think i figured this out. There's a method in the telephony.SmsMessage class called getMessageClass(). Class 0 would indicate a silent sms. As for sending them, that is still a work in progress

Comment: According to the [SMS wiki](http://www.sms-wiki.org/p_28-flash-sms.html), class 0 sms are so-called "flash sms", which aren't silent but are supposed to directly appear on the screen and won't be saved.

Answer (score 3):

Silent SMS may be initiated by the cellular operator (or potentially by an intruder) by setting bits 4-7 of the TP DCS (Data Coding Scheme) field to 1100 (Message Waiting Indication Group: Discard Message) - [see this article](http://www.ivizsecurity.com/blog/security-awareness/silent-sms-how-i-know-where-you-were-yesterday-night/), but AFAIK this is not reflected in the Android SDK.
Class 0 is not related to silent SMS.
3GPP 23.038 actually says "When a mobile terminated message is class 0 and the MS has the capability of displaying short messages, the MS shall display the message immediately and send an acknowledgement to the SC".

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing your application ...

Then I would suggest using the emulator tools for SMS.

On a windows machine -

1. Go to CMD
2. Type in - "telnet localhost 5554" (assuming this to be the only active emulator; if you have more emulators type in the corresponding port number)
3. use SMS feature (there are more options like gsm call, etc.)

You can also type help in telnet session, it will list out all possible things you can do.

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK supports Data SMS, as a subset of the general SMS received broadcast receiver capability:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" ></uses-permission>
```

You would need to specify an intent filter and listen on a specified port that matches that of the silent SMS:

```
 <intent-filter android:priority="10" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:port="16001" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents#DATA_SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION